# SOCKET IO: Is there a command in version 3 or 4 to disconnect all users from a room?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

What I would like is to be able to remove or clean all the connections in a room.

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code

Answer (score 1):

The `Server.socketsLeave` method was added in v4: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#server-socketsLeave-rooms

Example usage:

```js
// make all Socket instances leave the "room1" room
io.socketsLeave("room1");

// make all Socket instances in the "room1" room leave the "room2" and "room3" rooms
io.in("room1").socketsLeave(["room2", "room3"]);
```

The first example above will make all connected sockets leave the room `room1`, achieving what you need. Empty rooms are automatically "deleted", so this command is sufficient.

Comment: To leave the room is not the same as disconnecting sockets from a room. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

`io.in("room-101").disconnectSockets();`

According to the [official docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#disconnectsockets)